# Can't compile shared library in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, shared-libraries, lib

I'm trying to create a shared library in C++ using eclipse IDE on linux. But I'm getting this error and I can't find the problem:

```
23:42:12 **** Incremental Build of configuration Release for project GE ****
make all 
Building file: ../GE/Application.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
std=c++1y -DGE_PLATFORM_LINUX -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"GE/Application.d" -MT"GE/Application.o" -o "GE/Application.o" "../GE/Application.cpp"
/bin/sh: 1: -DGE_PLATFORM_LINUX: not found
make: [GE/subdir.mk:20: GE/Application.o] Error 127 (ignored)
Finished building: ../GE/Application.cpp

Building target: libGE.so
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -shared -o "libGE.so"  ./GE/Application.o   
g++: error: ./GE/Application.o: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [makefile:47: libGE.so] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

23:42:12 Build Failed. 1 errors, 0 warnings. (took 317ms)
```

This is my configuration:
[image: Preprocessor Settings]

[image: Dialect]

The preprocessor GE_PLATFORM_LINUX is required by the library.

Comment: Seems like it is missing the compiler from the command line and trying to execute the command line arguments instead. The first argument `std=c++1y`  is a valid shell variable assignment and tries to execute the second argument.

Comment: @drescherjm So how to solve it ?

Comment: Probably a setting in eclipse. Unfortunately I can't help with that.

Comment: I think I shouldn't use Eclipse... I will try tomorrow on Windows with Visual Studio, I will look for exporting the lib to linux later.

Comment: I won't disagree with that...

Comment: @PrograMedIP this is opening a big can of worms indeed, but I really fail to see why **anyone** would use Eclipse. On the other hand, resilience and resourcefulness are invaluable for software developer, so you might want to resolve this problem just for the challenge. You can learn a thing or two in the process.

Comment: @SergeyA It's actually because I found that it's one of the most used (and a little bit good looking) IDEs on linux, so I went for it...

Comment: @PrograMedIP anybody who uses IDE on Linux should be using CLion. But why do you need IDE in the first place? :)

Comment: Good looks aren't everything. In technical areas they are indeed one of the last things to look for, but not in marketing...

Comment: If I could make a suggestion I don't feel is actually an answer to your exact question but might save you some trouble: If this is a new project, this might be a great time to pick up and learn a nice **free** tool called Cmake, which makes configuring your project to build *vastly* simpler overall, and can generate IDE solutions/workspaces for you to jump into, including Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Your compilation command is all messed up.

> std=c++1y -DGE_PLATFORM_LINUX...
>
> /bin/sh: 1: -DGE_PLATFORM_LINUX: not found    make:
>   [GE/subdir.mk:20: GE/Application.o] Error 127 (ignored)

This means that the actual compiler (g++) was not invoked, and it is just the arguments following it, which is than treated by shell as a command, which obviously does not exist. Check your make file to see what is there.

Comment: I tried that but, the file was modified directly when I clicked "Build Project"

Comment: @SergeyA asked you to look at the makefile not modify it.

Comment: @drescherjm So if I don't modify anything, then how will it be possible to solve the problem.

Comment: It was more of verifying the exact nature of the problem.

Comment: There is a chance that looking at the Makefile could help discover what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
std=c++1y -DGE_PLATFORM_LINUX -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"GE/Application.d" -MT"GE/Application.o" -o "GE/Application.o" "../GE/Application.cpp"
```

In this line, the C++ compiler command is missing, which results in the shell trying to interpret `-DGE_PLATFORM_LINUX` as the command to execute. That results in the error showing up in the next line:

```
/bin/sh: 1: -DGE_PLATFORM_LINUX: not found
```

Thus the object file isn't built, and missing at link time. Why the missing command is accepted by Eclipse, and that error is ignored, are different questions.

Solution: Make sure you've set the correct compiler command; the linker call shows how it's supposed to look like:

```
g++ -shared -o "libGE.so"  ./GE/Application.o
```

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/38220551/5794048:
[image]

Comment: The makefile is auto-generated by Eclipse

Comment: I'm sure that everyone who commented on this knows that.

Comment: @PrograMedIP That may be the case, but it's generated from the data *you* entered into the project properties.

Comment: I don't think I changed something that looks like "g++" or other... @Murphy